# numpy add column of values to multidimentional array for differentiation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of shape as follows : (162060, 2, 128)
I performed differentiation using numpy.diff (as step equals 1)
now shape of differentiated array is : (162060, 2, 127) and I want the previous shape by adding zeros to the first column of the 2 arrays of each element i.e. (2,127) -> (2,128)

how can I perform this ? using numpy.concatenate doesn't help as it adds to the end and I want the zeros to be in the beginning

Comment: Please provide a code example that shows how `numpy.concatenate` adds zeros at the end, and I'm sure someone will be able to show you how to turn it around :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can expand in the ways of the other answers (or a proper use of concatenate, for that matter), I think it makes a bit more sense, from a code readability standpoint, to create the array of the write size, and explicitly differentiate into that array.  To me this is the most readable version.

```
derivatives = np.zeros_like(values)
derivatives[:,:,1:] = np.diff(values)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for numpy insert.
Read the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html)  here.

**Update**

To use numpys insert function, do it like follow:

```
X = np.insert(X, pos, obj, axis=0)
```

1. *X* specifies the target object to be inserted into
2. *pos* specifies where to insert
3. *obj* specifies what to insert
4. *axis=0* is optional and specifies the axis along which to insert values. If axis is None then arr is flattened first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add zeros (as an example), you could use [`numpy.pad()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) function:

```
import numpy as np
np.pad(array_to_expand, ((0, 0), (0, 0), (1, 0)), 'constant', constant_values=0)
```

Another option is to use [`numpy.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html#numpy.dstack):

```
np.dstack([np.zeros((162060, 2)), array_to_expand])
```

or,

```
np.dstack([np.zeros(array_to_expand.shape[:2]), array_to_expand])
```

Ah, and finally, [`numpy.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html#numpy.concatenate):

```
np.concatenate([np.zeros((162060, 2, 1)), array_to_expand], axis=2)
```

or,

```
np.concatenate([np.zeros(array_to_expand.shape[:2] + (1,)), array_to_expand], axis=2)
```